# How exactly works Angular HttpClient module? Why have I to subscribe the API call?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I am a complete beginner with Angular and TypeScript (I came from Java) and I am finding some difficulties to understand how exacly works the **HttpClient** module to perform HTTP Request to an external API.

So in my code I have this method performing a simple GET call toward an external API on the web:

```
  fetchCharacters() {
    this.http.get('https://swapi.dev/api/people/').subscribe(
      (response: Response) => {
        console.log(response);
      }
    )
```

My doubt is: why in Angular I have to **subscribe** the request? I have never seen something like this in Java\C#\Python...I always performed the request and obtained the response. Here it seems to me that **subscribe()** handle the request as an event. But what is the event in this case? Is it "getting a response"? So it means: when the "get a response from the called API happens, handle it with the lambda function defined ad **subscribe()** paramether"?

Is it the correct interpretation or am I missing something?
  }

Comment: Subscription triggers the reactive chain. It's like the terminal operations in Java streams. The event is basically the request that is mapped to a response. Think of it as a pipeline.

You can read more about it here: https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm

Comment: Angular wraps http request into Observable. Observables are lazy, meaning they won't be executed until we subscribe to them

Comment: In c# the equivalent can be seen when you use `async/await` when making a call that has to wait for I/O to complete. There are also callbacks you can subscribe to in the form of delegates or lambda functions. You could also block in c# but that is not advisable in javascript as there is only a single thread.

Answer (score 0):

you can try [await-for](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs-for-await) in certain cases, but maybe it is not ready for production yet

> npm i -S rxjs-for-await

and usually you no need subscribe

1. simple example, probably you will never use it production

```
    <ng-container *ngIf="{ data: fetchCharacters() | async} as source">
      <div *ngIf="source.data">
        {{ source.data }}
      </div>
    </ng-container>

    fetchCharacters() {
      return this.http.get('https://swapi.dev/api/people/');
    )
```

2. async/await [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-for-await?file=src/app/app.component.ts), looks useless with ngZone headache in UI, but could be useful for background tasks

```
    onClick() {
      const source$ = this.queryService.get();
      this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(async () => {

        for await (const data of eachValueFrom(source$)) {
          console.log(data);
        }

      });
    }
```

3. close to real life example with redux and async/await 
   see in [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mvc-for-await?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable.module%2Fstate%2Ftable.state.ts)

```
    @Action(TableUpdateAction)
    async updateAction(ctx: StateContext<TableStateModel>) {

      ctx.setState(patch({ data: [] }));

      const source$ = this.dataService.get();
      for await (const data of eachValueFrom(source$)) {
        ctx.setState(patch({ data }));
      }
    }
```